# how to case when statistics data row in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am writing a statistic query.

The case when statement is showing the total count according to the user's department position information.
When a date condition is added If there is no position updated or added on the date
The position does not show in the data row,

How can I display the positions in the CASE WHEN condition even if I do not have a position?
ex) position is counted as 0.

```js
SELECT CASE WHEN POSITION_NAME = 'Employee' THEN POSITION_NAME
   WHEN POSITION_NAME = 'Manager' THEN POSITION_NAME
   WHEN POSITION_NAME = 'Supervisor' THEN POSITION_NAME
   WHEN POSITION_NAME = 'Director' THEN POSITION_NAME
 ELSE 'Other' END AS TITLE
 , COUNT(POSITION_NAME) AS TOTAL_COUNT
FROM TB_USER
WHERE POSITION_NAME IS NOT NULL
AND DATE_FORMAT(REG_DATE, '%Y-%m-%d) BETWEEN '2021-10-01' AND '2021-10-01'
GROUP BY POSITION_NAME
```

Comment: Do you actually intended to `GROUP BY TITLE`?

Answer (score 0):

My feeling is that you want something along these lines:

```sql
SELECT
    CASE WHEN POSITION_NAME IN ('Employee', 'Manager', 'Supervisor', 'Director')
         THEN POSITION_NAME ELSE 'Other' END AS TITLE,
    COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_COUNT
FROM TB_USER
WHERE REG_DATE = '2021-10-01'
GROUP BY 1;
```

I have removed the null check in the `WHERE` clause.  Instead, in the above version any null position name would be bucketed under `Other` and would also be counted.